# :first-child but only if element before is not input[type="hidden"]

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a situation where I have set 25px top-margin and then if this element is first child I remove it.

e.q.

```
.div-name {
margin-top: 25px;

    &:first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

but sometimes I have `<input type="hidden" />` before and then I want to also remove the top margin but now it is not first-child.

How can I use &:first-child conditionaly?

Comment: Try `:not([type=hidden])` after `:first-child`

Answer (score 1):

```css
.div-name {
margin-top: 25px;

    &:first-child:not([type=hidden]) {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: already tired and it's not working...

Comment: Can you explain your issue in detail?

Comment: margin-top: 0 is not works on the .div-name if hidden is first element

Comment: can you add html and css.

Comment: it is a React component